What UX mistakes should be avoided when changing a service/product to a paid option?
The company I help is planning to change one of its functionalities from a currently free option to a paid option. We anticipate, of course, user dissatisfaction over such a move.
I'm wondering how user dissatisfaction can be minimized, what obvious UX mistakes should not be made, and what steps should be taken to ensure that users are fully aware of the upcoming change so that they can accept it or make the decision to abandon the service and move elsewhere as smoothly as possible.
The service I'm talking about is consultations with high-level specialists in the home finishing industry (interior architects). Currently, this option is unlimited free of charge for the company's clients, we want to introduce a consultation limit for a year (e.g. 3 consultations / year) after which, each subsequent consultation will be charged.
Thank you in advance for your advice on this topic :)

I cannot answer a complex question for an enterprise service, but I hope my experience with a product can help you. A year ago I purchased a baby monitor categorized as one of the best, also it was pricy (over $300 with taxes). The product was nice, but the software was something I liked about it because you didn't have to buy add-ons to make it work.
The first five months were awesome I was able to check temperature, cardiac rate, talk both ways over the monitor and other features from the app. Then the company was declared in bankruptcy, and it was decided to remove all the features from the application and put them in a service with a monthly fee named care+. In all moment the company informed via the app what was happening and the upcoming changes however I'm still feeling scammed.
Now I have a very expensive camera, the only thing that I can do it watch live and listen the audio, however it is not live because it has a delay of 3 to 5 secs that of course I realized when my baby felt off the bed.
Client experience is bad and I think the company could've done better by asking users which features were more important before they moved all to a paid plan.
Well, I hope you can get an insight from this little story.

